# How can I incorporate multiple p5.js canvases, each with an independent JavaScript file, into separate <div> elements within an HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, p5.js

I'm working on a project that involves using p5.js to create multiple canvases on a single HTML page. Each canvas should be contained within its own  element and use a distinct JavaScript file. I want to ensure that the canvases are independent of each other and controlled by their respective JavaScript files. I also want to "deactivate" one canvas by letting it either disappear completely or not run it at all without interfering with the other JavaScript files.

Comment: See [Can I create multiple canvas elements on same page using p5js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240287/can-i-create-multiple-canvas-elements-on-same-page-using-p5js) and [How to create more than one canvas with p5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55879820/how-to-create-more-than-one-canvas-with-p5)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.